# error en mi java script para integrar algo (mal ordenamiento)

Tags: javascript, jquery

hola que tal estoy trabajando en algo para un cliente el me pidió que se pudiera mover por inputs por las flechas del teclado mire este ejemplo

```
$(function() 
{
  $('.input').keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==37)//38 para arriba
      mover(e,-1);
    if(e.keyCode==39)//40 para abajo
      mover(e,1);
  });
});


function mover(event, to) {
   let list = $('input');
   let index = list.index($(event.target));
   index = (index + to) % list.length;
   list.eq(index).focus();
}
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-section" id="IpatCOp1-2">     
  <div class="md-form">
    <label class="label-input" for="IpatCOp1-org">No.</label>
    <input type="text" class="input" size="10" maxlength="8" id="IpatCOp1-org" tabindex="10"/>
  </div>
  <div class="md-form w-50">
    <label class="label-input" for="nomorganismo">NOMBRE</label>
    <input type="text" id="nomorganismo" class="w-100 input" tabindex="-1"/>
  </div>
  <div class="md-form w-50">
    <label class="label-input" for="nomorganismo">input3</label>
    <input type="text" id="input3" class="input" tabindex="-1"/>
  </div>
  <div class="md-form w-50">
    <label class="label-input" for="nomorganismo">input4</label>
    <input type="text" id="input4" class="w-100 input" tabindex="-1"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

este ejemplo ya lo intente implementar y no me funciona, ya vi que no es compatibilidad y quiero suponer que es por que cuando creo mi función aun no existen los input , yo muestro dentro de un modal un input para buscar después de eso muestro los resultado y cada uno tienen un input para agregar lo que encontró , en ese momento comienzan a existir los input

```
// general mi tabla con los input
$( "#info" ).change(function() {
                var info = $("#info").val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    contentType: 'json',
                    url: "{{route('info_producto')}}",
                    data: {data: info},
                    success:function(data){
                        var data = JSON.parse(data);

                        if(data.code == 200){
                            content = "<div class='table-responsive'>" +
                                "<table class='table'>" +
                                  "<thead>" +
                                    "<tr>" +
                                      "<th scope='col'>Cantidad</th>" +
                                      "<th scope='col'>Clave</th>" +
                                      "<th scope='col'>Nombre</th>" +
                                      "<th scope='col'>Descripcion</th>" +
                                    "</tr>" +
                                  "</thead>" +
                                  "<tbody>";

                            $.each(data.data, function(i, item) {
                                content += "<tr>" +
                                  "<td><input type='hidden' name='cantidades_ids[]' value='" + item.id + "'><input type='text' class='move form-control' name='cantidades[]' value=''></td>" +
                                  "<th scope='row'>" + item.clave + "</th>" +
                                  "<td>" + item.nombre + "</td>" +
                                  "<td>" + item.descripcion + "</td>" +
                                "</tr>";

                            })

                            content += "</tbody>" +
                                        "</table>" +
                                       "</div>";

                            $('#table-content').html(content);
                        }else{
                            $("#table-content").css('color', '#c4183c', 'margin-top','0.25rem', 'font-size','80%');
                            content ="Datos no encontrados.";
                            $('#table-content').html(content);
                        }
                    }
                })
// funciones para ell movimiento de los input 
$(function() 
{
  $('.move').keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==38)
      mover(e,-1);
    if(e.keyCode==40)
      mover(e,1);
  });
});


function mover(event, to) {
   let list = $('input');
   let index = list.index($(event.target));
   index = (index + to) % list.length;
   list.eq(index).focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar tu problema debes volver a llamar `keyup()` cuando realices cambios sobre el `dom` que implique volver a agregar elementos de la clases `.move`, dado que la que hace el fragmento de codigo

```
  // 1. busca lista de elementos con la clase "move" con $('.move')
  // 2. Agrega el evento keyup sobre cada elemento con .keyup(...)
  $('.move').keyup(...)
```

Así que los elementos que **aun no existe en el dom** no se le agregara este evento, por lo tanto debes volver a llamarlo, una buena opción es en el `complete:` de la función `ajax`; aquí un ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  escucharEventoToClassMove();
})

function escucharEventoToClassMove(){
  $('.move').keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.key === 'ArrowLeft')
      mover(e,-1);
    if(e.key === 'ArrowRight')
      mover(e,1);
  });
}

function mover(event, to) {
   let list = $('input');
   let index = list.index($(event.target));
   console.log(index)
   index = index + to;
   list.eq(index).focus();
}

//funcion para demostrar el cambio en el dom
function agregarInput(){
   $('table').append('<tr><td><input class="move"><td><tr>')
   $.ajax({
    complete: function(){
      escucharEventoToClassMove()
    }
   })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="agregarInput()">Agregar Input</button>
<table>
<tr>
 <td> <input class="move" name="foo[]"></td>
 <td><input class="move" name="foo[]"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <input class="move" name="foo[]"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Otro agregado fue que en vez de una `keyCode` uso el atributo `key` el cual retorna un string representando la letra sobre la que sucedió el evento..

Comment: hola amigo , no entiendo bien tu la parte del ajax

Comment: En tu llamado a la funcion `ajax` usa el parametro `complete` la cual permite pasar una funcion que se ejecutara siempre que se finalice la petición, lo cual requieres para actualizar la escucha de eventos en tu  `dom` ya que fue modificado.

Answer (score 0):

puedes delegar el evento, que te permite asignar el handler a un padre, y se se disparará siempre para los descendientes que cumplan el selector *independientemente de que existan en el momento de la declaración o se añadan posteriormente*

Sería algo así (puedes refinar más el selector si te hace falta):

```
$(function() 
{
  $('body').on('keyup', '.input', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==37)//38 para arriba
      mover(e,-1);
    if(e.keyCode==39)//40 para abajo
      mover(e,1);
  });
});
```